# Jobs - Canceling the asking of a question should not reload page and bring you back to top

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Go to a job, any job in which you can **Ask a Question**, such as this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/121698/backend-developer-rappi

Scroll down to the section to **ask a question**.  When the popup appears click the **Cancel** button.

Was expecting to popup to simply close.  Instead the page refreshes entirely and you are brought back to the top of the page.  A cancel should not do such a post back, it should simply close.

On the other hand, **canceling** an **apply now** works perfectly fine without a post back of any sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh, the `<a>` tag was missing the `cancel` class that we use to dismiss dialogs so it was causing a full reload.

Thanks for the report!